# Difference in Matrix Columns Sorted in reverse order

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Matrix table that performs a daily summary over the last 30 days.

I have used the previous function to get a difference between the columns and it worked very well.

## Day  01/05          01/06        01/07

### *[SUM]   [SUM] [DELTA]   [SUM] [DELTA]*

```
  100        105   5       98  (7)
```

Now management wants me to reverse the sort order of the table so that the most recent date shows first.

## Day   01/07          01/06      01/05

```
 *[SUM] [DELTA]  [SUM] [DELTA]   [SUM]*
     98   (7)      105   5        100
```

My problem is now the code I was using calculates using the original sort order and I get incorrect data.

```
***=(Previous(SUM(Fields!AggrSizeUsed_GB_.Value),"grp_ColumnDiff")-SUM(Fields!AggrSizeUsed_GB_.Value))***
```

Any help to correct this would be appreciated!